# how would you add a new dictionary element to a list of dictionary (json) and assign an increment value to each new key?

Tags: python, json, pandas, plotly, append

*I have a json file with a similar output of a couple of hundred line.
What should be the approach to add a new element "RANK" to each dictionary and assign an increment value to it? How can it be done using python?*

```
XYZ=json.load(open("countries.geo.json",'r'))
```

OUTPUT

```
**{'type': 'Feature',


'id': 'BEL',
  'properties': {'name': 'Belgium'},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[3.314971, 51.345781],
  [4.047071, 51.267259],
  [3.314971, 51.345781]]]}}



  {'type': 'Feature',
 'id': 'BLZ',
 'properties': {'name': 'Belize'},
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[-89.14308, 17.808319],
  [-89.150909, 17.955468],
  [-89.14308, 17.808319]]]}}**
```

> DESIRED OUTPUT

```
 **{'type': 'Feature',
'id': 'BEL',
'properties': {'name': 'Belgium'},
*'RANK':'1'*
'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
'coordinates': [[[3.314971, 51.345781],
 [4.047071, 51.267259],
 [3.314971, 51.345781]]]}}

 {'type': 'Feature',
 'id': 'BLZ',
 'properties': {'name': 'Belize'},
 *'RANK':'2'*
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[-89.14308, 17.808319],
 [-89.150909, 17.955468],
 [-89.14308, 17.808319]]]}}**
```

Comment: I noticed you tagged Plotly. Is this rank for coloring certain countries a specific color on a Plotly map?

Comment: Yes i am trying to achieve just that.

Comment: You don't need to modify your JSON to color your figure in Plotly

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "BEL",
        "properties": {"name": "Belgium"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [3.314971, 51.345781],
                    [4.047071, 51.267259],
                    [3.314971, 51.345781],
                ]
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "BLZ",
        "properties": {"name": "Belize"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-89.14308, 17.808319],
                    [-89.150909, 17.955468],
                    [-89.14308, 17.808319],
                ]
            ],
        },
    },
]

for i, d in enumerate(lst, 1):
    d["RANK"] = i

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "BEL",
        "properties": {"name": "Belgium"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [3.314971, 51.345781],
                    [4.047071, 51.267259],
                    [3.314971, 51.345781],
                ]
            ],
        },
        "RANK": 1,
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "BLZ",
        "properties": {"name": "Belize"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-89.14308, 17.808319],
                    [-89.150909, 17.955468],
                    [-89.14308, 17.808319],
                ]
            ],
        },
        "RANK": 2,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

With Plotly there is no need to alter your JSON. See reference [here](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/). All you would need is a separate dataframe that would need a column with a value that could be found in your JSON and a column containing whatever rank value you want.

Example directly from Plotly with a US county JSON

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           scope="usa",
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image: Fig 1]

If you need to show countries, you don't need a JSON file becasue county boundaries are built in.

Another example by Plotly

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="lifeExp", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
fig.show()
```

[image: Fig 2]